# How to call ServoBlaster from C#/Mono?

Tags: mono, servo

I have successfully installed [ServoBlaster](https://github.com/richardghirst/PiBits/tree/master/ServoBlaster), and it runs quite well from the terminal with the command

```
echo p1-22=250 > /dev/servoblaster
```

just like the documentation says.

However, when I try to call it from Mono with the code

```
string cmd = "echo p1-22=50 > /dev/servoblaster";;
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd; 
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

It does nothing and I get no error.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What Pi OS are you running?  Mono currently does not support [hardware floating point operating systems - armhf](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=7938).  According to [this blog entry](http://blog.alexrp.com/2013/07/21/recent-improvements-to-mono-on-arm/) support is coming for armhf

Comment: I am using Debian Wheezy (soft floating point) - I think the error is in how I am calling it, it works perfectly from the terminal/command line, just not from Mono.  I can use the camera module, but not the servoblaster.

Comment: Why do you need to execute a process for this?  Why can't you just do the writing to the device directly with this: `FileStream file = new FileInfo("/dev/servoblaster").OpenWrite();
StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.ASCII);
write.Write("p1-22=50");
write.Flush();`

Comment: Well, I didn't think about it for the most part...  Is that a faster way?  I very new to coding on the RaspberryPi/Mono

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try and use the *bash invocation read and execute* `-c` and quoted command line <sup>(This is supposed to solve character escaping)</sup>

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c 'echo p1-22=250 > /dev/servoblaster'"; 
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

But that might not work either so try and use `ProcessStartInfo` which inherently waits for everything to finish processing before exiting.

```
 string executable = "/bin/bash";
 string args = "echo p1-22=250 > /dev/servoblaster";

 ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(executable , args);
 procInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 procInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 procInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 procInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

 Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(procInfo);
 proc.WaitForExit();       
 int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
 proc.Close();
```

---

I had more luck with running a script file instead of running commands directly. This is most likely cause by character escaping that is required when passing args directly to bash. Making a script file with the commands inside them could solve the problem you are having.

```
touch servo.sh
chmod +x servo.sh
```

Add the commands into the script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo p1-22=250 > /dev/servoblaster
```

Comment: The first option (the addition of -c) worked!  Oddly, the second did not, but I am now moving via mono!  Thank you.